# Mongoose - push if array else update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema looks like this:

```
{
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    uid: { type: String, required: false, immutable: true },
    gid: [
        {
            type: String
        }
    ],
    status: { type: String, required: false }
}
```

I want to be able to save a new object everytime `uid` is new and update it when it already exists. So basically saving this object:

```
{
uid: "xyz",
gid: "123"
}
```

should produce

```
{
_id: ObjectId("123"),
uid: "xyz",
gid: ["123"]
// note that if status is not provided it shouldn't appear here as `null`
}
```

Then again if this object is saved:

```
{
uid: "xyz",
gid: "345",
status: "new"
}
```

it should produce:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("123"),
uid: "xyz",
gid: ["123","345"]
status: "new"
}
```

and lastly for this object:

```
{
uid: "xyz",
gid: "345",
status: "old"
}
```

the expected result would be

```
{
_id: ObjectId("123"),
uid: "xyz",
gid: ["123","345"]
status: "old"
}
```

Is this possible to achieve in a single query? Sorry if my explenation is complicated, I don't know how else to put it.

Comment: Hi, Can this requirement be done in mongo db query?

Answer (score 0):

Case1: only status changes and array exists, the below code, won't add a new element

```
> //actual code output from Mongo shell 4.2 on windows10 OS
> //use add to set and set update to acheive your update goals(array vs addition
> //of fields in two updates
> //add to set checks for an array element is present in array, if it is present it does nothing
> //else it will add the element in the array
> //pre-update document check
> db.ugs.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f625d864651219e25c775c1"),
        "uid" : "xyz",
        "gid" : [
                "345",
                "123",
                "100",
                "200"
        ],
        "status" : "old"
}
> var v_status = "new";
> db.ugs.aggregate([
... {$match:{uid: "xyz"}}
... ]).forEach(function(doc){
...     print("uid: ", doc.uid);
...     print("gid: ",doc.gid);
...     print("pre-status: ", doc.status);
...     db.ugs.update(
...     {"_id":doc._id},
...     {$addToSet:{gid:"200"}
...     });
...     db.ugs.update(
...     {"_id":doc._id},
...     {$set:{status:v_status}}
...     );
...     print("post-status: ", v_status);
... });
uid:  xyz
gid:  345,123,100,200
pre-status:  old
post-status:  new
> //post update document check
> db.ugs.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f625d864651219e25c775c1"),
        "uid" : "xyz",
        "gid" : [
                "345",
                "123",
                "100",
                "200"
        ],
        "status" : "new"
}
>
```

Case2: change status as well add element if it does not exists in array

```
> //pre-update document check
> db.ugs.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f625d864651219e25c775c1"),
        "uid" : "xyz",
        "gid" : [
                "345",
                "123",
                "100",
                "200"
        ],
        "status" : "new"
}
> var v_status = "old";
> db.ugs.aggregate([
... {$match:{uid: "xyz"}}
... ]).forEach(function(doc){
...     print("uid: ", doc.uid);
...     print("gid: ",doc.gid);
...     print("pre-status: ", doc.status);
...     db.ugs.update(
...     {"_id":doc._id},
...     {$addToSet:{gid:"444"}
...     });
...     db.ugs.update(
...     {"_id":doc._id},
...     {$set:{status:v_status}}
...     );
...     print("post-status: ", v_status);
... });
uid:  xyz
gid:  345,123,100,200
pre-status:  new
post-status:  old
> //post update document check
> db.ugs.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f625d864651219e25c775c1"),
        "uid" : "xyz",
        "gid" : [
                "345",
                "123",
                "100",
                "200",
                "444"
        ],
        "status" : "old"
}
>
```

Case3: set and unset the value of the status field as needed.

```
> db.ugs.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f625d864651219e25c775c1"),
        "uid" : "xyz",
        "gid" : [
                "345",
                "123",
                "100",
                "200",
                "444"
        ],
        "status" : ""
}
> var v_status = "";
> db.ugs.aggregate([
... {$match:{uid: "xyz"}}
... ]).forEach(function(doc){
...     print("uid: ", doc.uid);
...     print("gid: ",doc.gid);
...     print("pre-status: ", doc.status);
...     db.ugs.update(
...     {"_id":doc._id},
...     {$addToSet:{gid:"444"}
...     });
...     db.ugs.update(
...     {"_id":doc._id,status:{$exists:true}},
...     {$set:{status:v_status}}
...     );
...     print("post-status: ", v_status);
... });
uid:  xyz
gid:  345,123,100,200,444
pre-status:
post-status:
> //post update document check
> db.ugs.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f625d864651219e25c775c1"),
        "uid" : "xyz",
        "gid" : [
                "345",
                "123",
                "100",
                "200",
                "444"
        ],
        "status" : ""
}
//unset the field if not required, it will not show in the document
> var v_status = "";
> db.ugs.aggregate([
... {$match:{uid: "xyz"}}
... ]).forEach(function(doc){
...     print("uid: ", doc.uid);
...     print("gid: ",doc.gid);
...     print("pre-status: ", doc.status);
...     db.ugs.update(
...     {"_id":doc._id},
...     {$addToSet:{gid:"444"}
...     });
...     db.ugs.update(
...     {"_id":doc._id,status:{$exists:true}},
...     {$unset:{status:v_status}}
...     );
...     print("post-status: ", v_status);
... });
uid:  xyz
gid:  345,123,100,200,444
pre-status:  [unknown type]
post-status:
> //post update document check
> db.ugs.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f625d864651219e25c775c1"),
        "uid" : "xyz",
        "gid" : [
                "345",
                "123",
                "100",
                "200",
                "444"
        ]
}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking the `upsert` option to add a new doc if it doesn't exist already. Combined with the `addToSet` atomic opperator to create the array of gids.

You'll have to break the object into $set and $addToSet updaters with rest.

```
let saveObj = {
  uid: "xyz",
  gid: "123"
};

let {gid, ...setFields} = saveObj;

YourModel.updateOne(
  {uid: setFields.uid},
  {$set: setFields, $addToSet: {gid}},
  {upsert: true}
).then(...);
```